# Foundation 6 Installed with bower-rails Sass::SyntaxError

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I installed foundation 6 using `bower-rails` on a Rails app (Rails v4.2.6).

Imported it in my css via

```css
@import 'foundation-sites/scss/settings/settings';
@import 'foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

I get this error when I load the page

`Sass::SyntaxError in Controller#action
Invalid CSS after "...-flexbox: true ": expected "}", was "!global;"`

When I import the plain css files, it works but displays this error when I import the sass files.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Foundation 6 uses latest Sass syntax like '!global'.

Updating sass to the latest version should do the trick.

`$ gem update sass`

Hope that helps.